# How to change JW player controlbar position?

Tags: xml, position, jwplayer, skin

I have created my own JW player xml skin and I wonder if is it possible to change controlbar position to right instead of center?

Why is it centred only?

Comment: AFAIK, control bar position is not something you can change, without doing some fairly extensive hacking of the CSS that's buried in the script, and even then you'd have an awful time trying to change it for the Flash fallback (where it's not done with CSS). I don't think I've ever seen a non-centered control bar on a video player.

Comment: The controlbar will always be in an over position, and will always fade.